# PHP sorting opendir file includes

Tags: php, sorting, opendir

I am trying to sort an opendir() listing so that it can display the information in the order I've named it.

Each file in the directory is called 1_something.php, 2_something.php, 3_something.php, etc.  these files are small bits of templated html that I change to whatever I need it to say.

I am using the code below to pull and show these files:

```
$dir = "./portfolio"; 
if($handle = opendir($dir)) { 
    while($file = readdir($handle)) { 
        clearstatcache(); 
        if(is_file($dir.'/'.$file)) {
            include("portfolio/".$file);
        }
    } 
closedir($handle); 
}
```

I have been playing around with creating an array of the names and sorting them, though I guess I don't know exactly where the array happens, where the sorting happens and where the actual displaying of information happens.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your `clearstatcache()` can be outside of your loop btw :)

Comment: Thank you Jack, I guess it's best to only call it once, when it's needed, eh?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credit goes to [@SiGanteng](https://stackoverflow.com/users/135448/siganteng) on this one

I just had to add another line to make sure it was only looking at real files:  Code Below

```
$dir = "./portfolio"; 
$files = scandir($dir); // returns array of files, sorted alphabetically

foreach($files as $file) {
    if(is_file($dir.'/'.$file)) {
        include("portfolio/".$file);
    }
}
```

This is the simplest way to return results in ascending order.
Thank you again [SiGanteng](https://stackoverflow.com/users/135448/siganteng)

Answer (score 1):

Hm, anything preventing you from using `scandir`?

http://sg.php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php

```
$files = scandir($dir); // returns array of files, sorted alphabetically
foreach($files as $file) {
   // your code
}
```

Comment: This is somewhat working, though I'm getting errors such as
Warning: include() [function.include]: Failed opening 'portfolio/..' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php5')
it's looking for a file called portfolio/..  
I'll try adding a "if it's a file" into this as well tomorrow morning

Comment: Ok, I created a quick if statement, the code looks like this now

`$dir = "./portfolio"; 
$files = scandir($dir); // returns array of files, sorted alphabetically
foreach($files as $file) {
 if($file !== "." && $file !== ".."){
     include("portfolio/".$file);
 }
}`

What do you think? Is this a problem at all?

Comment: @ntgCleaner Looks ok to me :)

Comment: `scandir` should more resource consuming then `opendir`.